# Nissan LEAF Operation in 0F, -20C weather

Tags: nissan, leaf

Is there any public data on LEAF operation at -20C?  We routinely see those kinds of temperatures in the winter, and I am trying to understand the viability of a LEAF.

My understanding is that newer models have heaters for the HV battery, which would improve performance, but may require keeping the car "plugged in" overnight.

My understanding is that in general, power losses are about 50% for every 10F battery temperature drop below a certain point (approx 0C).

Comment: Have you contacted the Nissan dealer?

Comment: Yes, and the sales people are happy to report that they sell cars in this area.  They point out that there are new battery systems (aka heater) to help the battery operate more efficiently.  They want to sell, and I want to understand.

Comment: I think your best bet will be to call the Nissan regional office directly. They can tell you what the operation limits of the Leaf are.

Comment: Easier said than done.  I have made numerous phone calls.  But the point of this post is that I am looking for data, which may not be from the marketing department, which might substantiate the performance of the vehicle during near-arctic operations.  Of course they will tell me that the car is well suited for all areas that they market it, but if I have to leave it plugged in at work, so that the battery says warm, I would like to know that.